# Veeva CRM App: “Incorrect Packaging Structure”

Tags: salesforce

I´m in the middle of a content creation project for Salesforce/Veeva. I´ve created Key Messages according to the Veeva CLM Content Creation Guidelines zipped them and uploaded them using the salesforce.com backend into the sandbox.

The Key Messages get synced with the Veeva CRM App on my iPad, but there, the Key Message files are shown in the media overview with "Incorrect Packaging Structure".

I have used this directory structure

```
my_message_slide01/
  Index.html
  thumb.png
  assets/
    css/
    img/
    js/
```

resulting in my_message_slide01.zip. Error message "Incorrect Packaging Structure"

I also used these directory structures according to the Veeva CLM Content Creation Guidelines:

```
my_message_slide01/
  my_message_slide01-full.jpg
  my_message_slide01-thumb.jpg
  my_message_slide01.html
  assets/
    css/
    img/
    js/
```

and

```
my_message_slide01/
  my_message_slide01-full.jpg
  my_message_slide01-thumb.jpg
  my_message_slide01.html
  css/
  img/
  js/
```

These also lead to the error message "Incorrect Packaging Structure"

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks in advance

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the structure attached as image to upload in salseforce keymessage and key message name should be the same name CLM_Legacy_HTML.

[zip_for_salseforce_upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QMmr.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. It seems, that there were initially not well-formed .zip-files that weren´t removed by updating from the salesforce.com backend. Re-building the local database in the Veeva CRM app solved the issue.

Comment: That system can be a headache until you get it right.